# Proxy class defined by interfaces not found

Tags: java, quarkus

This error suddenly occurred when I try to use the feature from **awssdk**.

The full error log is:

```
com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy class defined by interfaces [interface 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager, interface org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl, interface com.amazonaws.http.conn.Wrapped] not found. 
Generating proxy classes at runtime is not supported. Proxy classes need to be defined at 
image build time by specifying the list of interfaces that they implement. To define proxy 
classes use -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=<comma-separated-config-files> and - 
H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=<comma-separated-config-resources> options.
Error id 9c0a59d0-dd65-4156-8c8b-33d46676e1c3-62
```

I have followed some instructions and created a custom proxy configuration in **src/main/resource/dynamic-proxy.json**:

```
[ 
  ["org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager", "org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl","com.amazonaws.http.conn.Wrapped"]
]
```

And defined It in **src/main/resource/application.yaml**:

```
quarkus:
  native:
    additional-build-args: -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json,-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=dynamic-proxy.json
```

But the code isn't working at all.
Can you please point out what I'm missing? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using **newProxyInstance** and it works for me adding the following two parameters

Documentation

https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/DynamicProxy/

**-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=dynamic-proxy.json**

**-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=dynamic-proxy.json**

Example in *application.properties*

```
additional-build-args: -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json,-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=dynamic-proxy.json,-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=dynamic-proxy.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using **Retrofit2** and it works for me adding the following  parameters

**-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=dynamic-proxy.json**

only and not
-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=dynamic-proxy.json

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed this:

```
[
  {"interfaces":["io.fouad.demo.dao.ADao", "io.fouad.demo.dao.BDao"]}
]
```

to:

```
[
  {"interfaces":["io.fouad.demo.dao.ADao"]},
  {"interfaces":["io.fouad.demo.dao.BDao"]}
]
```